# Why is との used in this?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Going through a passage and 大事にしなければいけないとの意見も多数。is written, and I don'tknow how to interpretthe との here.

Plz help :P

Thank you! That seems so obvious to me now...

Answer (score 2):

> 大事{だいじ}にしなければいけない**との**意見{いけん}も多数{たすう}。

≒

> 『大事にしなければいけない』**との**意見も多数。
>
> ("The majority opinion was that (it) had to be valued/cherished/taken good care of.")

First, the 「と」 is a quotative particle here, quoting the opinion 「大事にしなければいけない」.

The 「の」 is needed to connect the quote and the noun 「意見」("opinion").  As you know, only a noun can directly follow a 「の」.

「～～との意見」 = "the opinion that ~~"

「～～との考{かんが}え」 = "the idea that ~~"

「～～とのメッセージ」 = "a/the message saying ~~"

Answer (score 1):

If you know the phrase "という", that との is the same as it.